# Generate list of week number + start date + end date against any year using SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000

I want to generate a temp table with the following columns:

- WeekNO
- StartDate
- EndDate

using an UDF having a year parameter (`YEAR(YYYY)`).

Comment: Which type of week - weeks starting from 01 January, ISO weeks or some other weeks?

Answer (score 3):

[Why should I consider using an auxiliary calendar table?](http://web.archive.org/web/20150411042510/http://web.archive.org/web/20150411042510/http://sqlserver2000.databases.aspfaq.com/why-should-i-consider-using-an-auxiliary-numbers-table.html)

Comment: Excellent advice, +1.  Might edit the answer to show how the OP's temp table is then filled by one simple select (or not needed at all).

Comment: link is broken. Please post the correct answer here and provide the link as reference